# Adding Materialize to Jekyll (github pages)

Tags: jekyll, materialize, github-pages

I try to add [materialize](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html) to my Github pages served by jekyll. I want to add carousel as follows:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>
```

I added css and js to the `assets` folder of my website.

[image]

After `jekyll serve` html page compiles and I get the following [file](https://gofile.io/?c=nvgyUV).

The links to css/js work but I still get empty page, with pictures.

[image]

How can I get materialize working with Github pages?

Comment: Answering your only question, yes you can get materialize working with Github pages. [Here](https://github.com/multimediaeval/multimediaeval.github.io) is an example.

I'm quite sure that is not the only thing you want to know.